# Entity Framework null object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have simple DBcontext class called OdeToFoodDb:

```
public class OdeToFoodDb: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Restaurant>()
            .HasMany(resturant => resturant.Reviews)
            .WithRequired(review => review.Resturant);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

and the class definition:

```
public class Restaurant
{
    //public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual int RestaurantId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}

public class Review : IValidatableObject
{
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Digning Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 10)]
    public int Rating { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
    public Restaurant Resturant { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var fields = new[]{ "Created"};

        if(Created > DateTime.Now)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Created date cannot be in the future.", fields);
        }

        if (Created < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Created date cannot be to far in the past.", fields);
        }
    }
}
```

my problem is when i select a review from dbcontext like this:

```
    OdeToFoodDb _db = new OdeToFoodDb();
    public PartialViewResult LatestReview()
    {
        var review = _db.Reviews.FindTheLatest(1).Single();
        //************************************
        return PartialView("_Review", review);
    }
```

I checked that the review.Restaurant is null! while the other property have a value. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you not missing an include of the Restaurant object in your query? I'm not sure what FindTheLatest is doing but this should be _db.Reviews.Include(r => r.Restaurant).FindTheLatest(1).Single() or _db.Reviews.Include("Restaurant").FindTheLatest(1).Single()

Comment: @Khepri I am new to entity framework. Can you alaborate what 'Include' Method does?

Comment: Include loads the navigation property in your result. If you do not include that statement, the results for the navigation property are not populated.

Comment: I am sure that FindTheLatest returns last review. I debugged it. But Restaurant property is null!

Comment: @Khepri i used Include( Both of above code) but i get following error:
A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'OdeToFood.Models.Review' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Restaurant'.

Comment: Use your spelling, "Resturant". The include is looking for a navigational property with the name you give, in your case "Resturant".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either load navigation property `Restaurant` explicitly via `Include` method:

```
var review = _db.Reviews.Include(r => r.Restaurant).FindTheLatest(1).Single();
```

or you can enable lazy loading for that property, by making it virtual:

```
public virtual Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
```

You can read more about loading related entities [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232).

Comment: Can you tell me in the above code, what does keyword 'virtual' ?

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi: `virtual` property in any entity type is a mark for the context to make dynamic proxies, when working with instances of that entity type. In particular, with navigation properties, this means, that context supplies lazy loading - when you call property getter, proxy object loads property value and returns result. I've added a link to an answer.